# How to view the actual objc method signature in swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, interface, method-signature

Example of code:

```
/**
 Device types.
 */
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, STDeviceType) {
/**
 The device is not defined.
 */
    STDeviceTypeNone = 0,
/**
 Real device.
 */
    STDeviceTypeHardware = 1 << 0,
/**
 A device simulator.
 */
    STDeviceTypeSimulator  = 1 << 1
};

@interface TestSwiftInterface : NSObject

+ (void)enableVisibilityErrorIndicatorForDeviceType:(STDeviceType)deviceType;

+ (void)enable2VisibilityErrorIndicatorForDeviceType:(YMADeviceType)deviceType;

@end
```

Where STDeviceType is a full copy of YMADeviceType from [YandexMobileAds library](https://cocoapods.org/pods/YandexMobileAds) and `enableVisibilityErrorIndicatorForDeviceType` is the same as `enable2VisibilityErrorIndicatorForDeviceType` (I add one number to one method name to avoid "duplication").

Xcode shows swift interface:

```
/**
 Device types.
 */
public struct STDeviceType : OptionSet {

    public init(rawValue: UInt)

    
    /**
     Real device.
     */
    public static var hardware: STDeviceType { get }

    /**
     A device simulator.
     */
    public static var simulator: STDeviceType { get }
}

open class TestSwiftInterface : NSObject {

    
    open class func enableVisibilityErrorIndicator(for deviceType: STDeviceType)

    
    open class func enable2VisibilityErrorIndicator(forDeviceType deviceType: Any!)
}
```

In the same time code autompletion and compiler works with `enable2VisibilityErrorIndicator` as if it has signature:

```
open class func enable2VisibilityErrorIndicator(for deviceType: YMADeviceType)
```

There a lot of similar questions how to view objc method signature in swift but no one describes this situation. So how to view the actual method signature if "generated swift interface" is incorrect?

Comment: "Xcode shows swift interface" But you can ask for the ObjC interface instead, so why not do that?

Comment: I need to create a documentation for my project on Swift so I can't just take objc. In other words I need to describe how to call ObjC code from Swift but xcode has bugs with displaying Swift interface.

Comment: I don't know about the "documentation" part, but if you think you've found an Xcode bug, file it with Apple.

Comment: I usually create a unit test written in objective C (with .m extension) and implement  the code I expect to be implemented in objective C there. Same code then can be copied to documentation. Bonus points: if you break objc compatibility in the future, the test will fail, so you know you broke it.